# Theorem about monotone function's limit.

Tags: limits, proof-explanation

$f:Df \rightarrow R, \forall x\in Df x<a, a\in D'f, Df \subset R, f$ - monotonic.  Then

$1) \exists \lim_{x \to a }f(x)$

2) $f - increasing \Rightarrow lim_{x \to a}f(x)=sup<f(x)|x \in Df>$

3)$f - decreasing \Rightarrow lim_{x \to a}f(x)=inf<f(x)|x\in Df>$

Case when f - increasing, $supRf \in R, a\in R, x<a$.

Proof: $b:=sup<f(x)|x\in Df>$

$b \in R  \Rightarrow \forall x \in Df \ \ f(x)\le b$

Does $lim_{x \to a}f(x)=b?$

Does $\forall \epsilon > 0 \ \ \exists \delta >0: \forall x \in Df x\in (a - \delta; a + \delta) \Rightarrow f(x) \in (b - \epsilon; b+ \epsilon)?$ Because $\forall x\in Df x<a \ \ x\in (a-\delta;a)$ and because $b - sup., f(x)\notin (b;b+\epsilon) $. Does $f(x) \in (b-\epsilon;b)?$
Take a point $x'$. Then if $\epsilon>0$ given $b=sup<f(x)|x\in Df> \ \Rightarrow \exists x'\in Df : f(x')>b-\epsilon $ 
Then if $x'<x \Rightarrow f(x')\le f(x)$

$x' \in (a-\delta;a)\ \  x'>a-\delta $ then $\delta=a-x'$, t.i., $\delta$ exists.

I don't understand why $x'\in (a-\delta;a)?$  why it is important to note, that if $x'<x \Rightarrow f(x')\le f(x)$, how does it help to prove that $x'\in(a-\delta;a)?$

Comment: The main problem here is overuse of symbols. Can you really translate the result in question into your natural language? As far as I can see the domain here is an interval of type $(c, a) $ and limit being considered is of type $\lim_{x\to a^{-}} $.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh That would take a loads of time, if I had to put into words every symbol. Yes, it is one sided limit, because $\forall x \in Df x<a$

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to state the result as follows: if $f$ is monotone on an interval $I$ then $f$ possesses one sided limits at each interior point of $I$. The proof of such a result would indicate that the desired limits are sup and inf of appropriate sets. Understanding is always in natural language rather in math symbols.